# Does anyone know sed -i implementation?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

When I executing sed with -i option (replace file) against very large file, is there any way to know how about target file processed.
e.g. creating intermediate file at /tmp , or processed on the memory and swapped etc.

Comment: `sed -i` creates a temporary file and moves it over the original when it's done.  If you want to modify the file truly in place try `ed` instead

Comment: You could also [look at the source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed), or use a tool like [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to see exactly what the tool is doing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: thank you all. I found ck_mkstemp in source code

Answer (score 1):

`strace` shows that even for small files the original file is read, the results are written to a temporary file and then renamed to the name of the original file.
So I would assume that this is the same behaviour for larger files: a temporary file will be created.